# Create React App install in Mac says MODULE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: npm, webpack, create-react-app

I was trying to install Create React App using `npm install -g create-react-app` . The installation runs well without problem. There was an error that popped up when I entered `npm start` which is similar to snapshot below. I am using macOS High Sierra version 10.13.x and npm version 13.6.4.

Even though it says "Successfully created my-app", `cd my-app` and then `npm start` running the command in console shows following lines of errors that goes like,MODULE_NOT_FOUND.
Do anyone knows that version of npm has a issue installing create react app in Mac, please help.

i.e. >

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628
  throw e;
  ^

Error: No valid exports main found for '/Users/Nirmala1/React/my-app/node_modules/postcss-safe-parser/node_modules/postcss'

 at resolveExportsTarget (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:625:9)
    at applyExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:502:14)
    at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:22)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:960:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:855:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1033:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Nirmala1/React/my-app/node_modules/postcss-safe-parser/lib/safe-parse.js:1:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1144:30) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Comment: upgrading node.js to v14.5 worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this problem by upgrading node.js to v14.5, i've had v13.5 and v13.6 before on my Mac.Tried to solve by removing create-react-app globally:
`npm uninstall -g create-react-app`
and using:
`npx create-react-app myapp`

But it didn't work for me. I installed latest version of node using `curl -o- url` command to download, like
`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.0/install.sh | bash`

and to install using nvm install version. `nvm install v14.15.1`
and `npx create-react-app myapp`
worked well by loading create react app page in http://localhost:3000/.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue with code: `'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'` on Ubuntu. I was using an older version of node at the time. All I had to do was to upgrade to the latest version by using the Node Version Manager nvm

Type in the command line:

```sh
nvm install stable
```

That should get you the latest version and then go back to your react app and do as before npm start.